# Finding a disabled field with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a select box, with a label:

```
<label for="slide_orientation">Slide orientation</label>
<select disabled="" class="property" id="slide_orientation" name="slide_orientation">
  <option value="horizontal">Horizontal</option>
  <option value="vertical" selected="selected">Vertical</option>
</select>
```

As you can see the select box is disabled. When I try to find it with `field_labeled("Slide orientation")`, it returns an error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Slide orientation"
from /Users/pascal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/result.rb:22:in `find!'
```

When the select box is not disabled, `field_labeled("Slide orientation")` returns the select element just fine.

Is this expected behavior? And if so, how would I go about finding a disabled element? In my case I need it to test if it's disabled or not.

Comment: The situation is the same for buttons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917227/how-do-i-write-a-capybara-assertion-that-checks-for-the-presence-of-a-button-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andreas and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515097/414376) put me on the track to the final solution. Finding a disabled field with a certain label (instead of HTML id) can be achieved this way:

```
label_field = all("label").detect { |l| (l.text =~ /#{label}/i).present? }
raise Exception.new("Couldn't find field '#{label}'") if label_field.nil?
the_actual_field = first("##{label_field[:for]}")
```

Checking if that field is disabled can be done with one statement:

```
page.should have_css("##{label_field[:for]}[disabled]")
```

It still feels like a workaround instead of the best Capybara-like solution, but it works!

Comment: ouch, unfortunately only works for <label for=""> structures. I usually wrap labels around the radio buttons, so I will have to figure out something else

Answer (score 38):

[Capybara 2.1.0 supports `disabled` filter](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/982). You can easily find disabled fields with it.

```
field_labeled("Slide orientation", disabled: true)
```

You need to specify it explicitly because the `disabled` filter is off by default.

Answer (score 12):

This one passes if it has the disabled attribute.

Run with `js: true` and `page.evaluate_script`.

```
it "check slider orientation", js: true do
    disabled = page.evaluate_script("$('#slide_orientation').attr('disabled');")
    disabled.should == 'disabled' 
end
```

**Update**

or you can use `have_css`

```
page.should have_css("#slide_orientation[disabled]")
```

(stolen form [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153771/440032) )

Comment: `expect(find("slide_orientation")).to be_disabled`

Answer (score 12):

Since the answers to this are old and things have moved on a little since then here is an **UPDATE**.

If you just want to check if a field is disabled you can now do:

```
expect(page).to have_field 'Slide orientation', disabled: true
```

As per this PR:
https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/982